# Wordpress отправка писем через Postman SMTP

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp

Установил Postman SMTP, настроил, тестовое письмо отправляет.
Как подключить форму к этому плагину?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никаких действий не требуется. Установите Contact From 7, например, и отправляйте почту.

Comment: Если у меня уже есть форма, сверстанная вручную, как в таком случае?

Comment: А почему не попробовать просто отправить письмо стандартными средствами WordPress? Postman замещает библиотеку PHPmailer своей библиотекой. Простая отправка письма должна работать.